# Vertical divs that expand and contract on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expand

My goal is to have five or so divs inside a parent div. When a div is clicked it should expand over the other divs.  What confuses me is how to get said div to expand above the other divs so when the reset/back/close button is clicked all of the divs are shown once again.

When hovered, the div should expand slightly.

The parent container is 1900 by 500.

My code:

```css
.one {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #ffccaa;
  float: left;
}
.two {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  float: left;
}
.three {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #aabbcc;
  float: left;
}
.four {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  float: left;
}
.five {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #ff11bb;
  float: left;
}

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.header {height: 50vh; width: 100vw; background-color: #000;}
.navi {height: 100px; width: 100%; background-color: #fccaab; margin-top: 5px;}
.logo {height: 100%; width: 500px; background-color: #ccc; align:center; margin: auto;}
.content {height: auto; width: 100%; background-color: #ccffca; margin-top: 5px;}
.footer {height: 10vh; width: 100%; background-color: #abcdef; margin-top: 5px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/file.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>       
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="one"></div>
            <div class="two"></div>
            <div class="three"></div>
            <div class="four"></div>
            <div class="five"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="navi">
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="footer">
        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Could you post some code or attempts?

Comment: Done. Thank you sir. I don't know jquery. began learning tonight from an online school. I understand it quite well. Maybe its because I get javascript. I just need this part for my website and I would be nearly done.

Comment: "*That isn't hard right"*, *"that would be simple enough to add, right.?"* - If you yourself knows it is easy, please make some effort to do it by yourself. And when you're stuck with something specific, then ask. You're asking many things which means you're not making any effort.

Comment: What i was referring to as being easy is adding the background image to each div. If I thought the whole task was easy i would have just done it myself. That was insulting, TJ!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example the clicked div is given 100% width and its siblings have their width removed. The [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) gives a smooth animation.

Create the hover with the `:hover` pseudo class on the div. In this example, the div is scaled slightly using the [transform scale property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale) like this:

```
body > div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);  
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The scale is removed when selected with `.selected:hover { transform: scale(1) }`

### Working Example

**Note:** I have changed all the ids to classes and condensed all the duplicate styles into `body > div`; all the direct div children of body have the same width, height, transition, and are floated to the left.

```js
$('body > div').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body > div {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}
body > div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.one {
  background-color: #ffccaa;
}
.two {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
}
.three {
  background-color: #aabbcc;
}
.four {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.five {
  background-color: #ff11bb;
}
.selected {
  width: 100%;
}
.selected:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.hide {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
<div class="five"></div>
```

Comment: $('body>div') Will not work for me. Its going  into an existing website. Im gonna find attempt to find a new way around this.

Comment: `body > div` could become `.container .box`. Place the divs in a parent with a class such as `container` and give the divs inside a class, the same class for each inner div.

Comment: Hello, again. I tried many times to get this to work. I've updated the post to show you all my my sites code. I'm feeling very stupid here. I've been trying to get it on my own when ever I had some time on my hands. it just isn't working for me.

Comment: Hi, copy and paste everything you have at the moment into a jsbin and post the link as a comment here. Use this link to get started: http://jsbin.com/?html,css,js,output.

Comment: Ok.Just for the record. Im using brackets to develop my site. When I entered the code on S.O. it worked better now im gonna hit up jsbin.

Comment: @UnCreatedVirus - [Here is your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9doo6f2v/). I have provided some explanation about what is going on in the CSS comments. Basically, you were not providing hover or selected properties.

Comment: DUDE! You have my thanks. I wish I had money to give you. Something I could give to you. You have went out of your way for me and I thank you for it. Thank you sir! I greatly appreciate it!!!!